# How to use this phpcgi apache tempalte to run php 5.2

Tags: apache-2.2, php

From vestacp documentation  (the CP I use)
"phpcgi - tempalte to run php as cgi. can be useful to run php4 or php5.2"
here is the source of the template 
http://c.vestacp.com/0.9.8/rhel/templates/web/httpd/phpcgi.tpl

I set this as template for a site, used the rebuild option from the drop down menu for that user.
But still the script that needs php 5.2 doesn't run adn phpinfo() says PHP Version 5.5.9

Since im very new to this I have no idea if:
1. phpinfo() should show php 5.2 at all in that setup
2. if i  need to instal php 5.2 somehow as well, side to  side with the one already installed?

Comment: No, you need to fix or replace the PHP script. Attempting to run PHP 5.2, or even anything older, is utterly irresponsible.

Comment: Tried that already. Turns out is better to use php 5.2 so please help me do that.